# cat boost Feature has 'Categorical type in training data but 'Float' type in test dataset

Tags: python, categorical-data, catboost

I am working with catboostclassifier, and I have a training dataset and a validation dataset. Each dataset have the same 5 columns, and there is one column named 'colC' that is categorical (column 'colC' is formatted as int). I tested the dataframes and in the 'colC' column has the same data type in both dataframes.

When i executing the next code I got an error:

```
val_pool = Pool(X_validation, y_validation)

estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set = val_pool, sample_weight = sample_weights, cat_features = ['colC'])
```

The error is the next:

```
catboost/libs/data/features_layout.cpp:391: Feature #3 has 'Categorical' type in training data, but 'Float' type in test dataset #0
```

Which can be the reason?

Comment: How did youseparate your train/test data? Using train_test_split  method?

Comment: I got a training set with 1000 elements and I extract the last 100 elements for validation using X_validation = X_train.iloc[900:, :]

Comment: I think the problem is you did not convert `y_train` and `y_test` using keras `to_categorical` method. For instance: `y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes) and` `y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)`. Did you convert like that?

Comment: The error still continues...

Comment: When I try the code removing the eval_set from the estimator.fit() the code works... I mean, removing the validation set and letting only the training X and y the code works

Comment: Converting using `to_categorical` method is suggested on the official documentation. https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/mnist_convnet.py

Comment: I think this documentation is for a neural network approach

Comment: Yes you could say that, but NN, CNN, catboost, light-gbm, extreme-gradient-boost etc. are all extract features from the given data. Therefore using `to_categorical` is a common approach.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who comes across this post: I managed to solve this issue when I encountered it by specifying the cat_features list in Pool as well as fit.

```
val_pool = Pool(X_validation, y_validation, cat_features = ['colC'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be solved using `to_categorical` method.

For instance:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

Comment: Yes, I applied it to both y_train and y_validation